# CASE statement inside a WHERE clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, select, case, where-clause

I am trying to add a CASE statement, but I need an OR within it and I am having a little trouble.

I'm not sure how I can do this, but I was hoping someone could help. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Table1
 WHERE IsUpdate = CASE WHEN @Type = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE (0 OR 1) END
```

So basically, I want to select only the rows that have IsUpdate set to 1 when @Type = 'Yes', otherwise I want to select the rows where IsUpdate = 0 OR IsUpdate = 1. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a `CASE`, i assume that the value can only be `0` or `1`:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE @Type <> 'Yes' OR IsUpdate = 1
```

If this is sitting in a stored-procedure it's probably better to use a `If-Else` instead of the parameter-check since above query is [non-sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) so it might be inefficient on a large table.

Comment: Well, it's most certainly been a long day. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The full `where` clause that matches your logic is:

```
where (@Type = 'Yes' and IsUpdate = 1) or
      (@Type <> 'Yes' and IsUpdate in (0, 1))
```

You can simplify this, if you know something about the values in the columns.  For instance, if `IsUpdate` *only* takes on the values `0` and `1` (and not `NULL`):

```
where @Type <> 'Yes' or IsUpdate = 1
```